# HTACCESS Redirection from subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i am Working on a redirect script

i want to redirect all links contaning /en/

For eg redirect link like this

```
http://example.com/en/some-text/123-some-text-123456.html
```

to

```
http://example.com/some-text/123-some-text-123456.html
```

I am trying with this script but not workin as of now

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\en\(.*)
RewriteRule http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple by using this

```
Redirect 301 http://example.com/en/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Use this - with the %1 modifier you can access the extract group from the previous RewriteCond.